# How do I make 2 columns unique together?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 columns:

- confirmed_email
- unconfirmed_email

I don't want them to overlap. I want:

- confirmed_email to be unique
- unconfirmed_email to be unique
- confirmed_email + unconfirmed_email to be unique, if merged together. If "hello@gmail.com" exists in confirmed_email ,then it cannot be updated into unconfirmed_email.

Is there a setting for this?

Comment: If you want to handle this at DB level you will need trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that you really want to store two emails.

Use one field and add a BOOL field which stores whether the email was confirmed.

Comment: I think what he want to accomplish is procedure to change email after confirmation. He need to store both emails.